# Hadwiger's conjecture in the language of graph homomorphisms

Tags: co.combinatorics, graph-theory, graph-minors

Consider the following statement:

> (S): If $G$ is not a complete graph, then there is a minor $M$ of $G$ such that
>
> 1. $M \not \cong G$, and
> 2. there is a graph homomorphism $f:G\to M$.

[Hadwiger's conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hadwiger_conjecture_(graph_theory)) states that for every finite simple undirected graph $G$, the complete graph  $K_{\chi(G)}$ is a minor of $G$. Since colorings $G$ are homorphisms from $G$ to some complete graphs, it is not hard to see that in the finite case, Hadwiger's conjecture is equivalent to (S). Now, the statement of Hadwiger's conjecture is **false** for graphs with infinite chromatic number (see for example the disjoint union of all $K_n, n\in\mathbb{N}$).

**Question.** Does statement (S) hold for graphs with infinite chromatic number?

(This is a follow-up to [this](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/221612/does-this-version-of-hadwigers-conjecture-hold-for-graphs-with-infinite-chromat) question.)